# Tornado async download to client error: Cannot send error response after headers written

Tags: python, tornado

I am trying to create a tornado web app for downloading local file from server to client through a html `href`. I am able to hit the download endpoint, something is not correct in my code. It takes 20 sec before error in terminal shows up, the test file is a very small csv file, 11 bytes. The traceback I get:

```
Uncaught exception GET /data/test.csv (::1)
HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8888', method='GET', uri='/data/test.csv', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1786, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "/tornado_extra_endpoint.py", line 24, in get
    response = await client.fetch(url, streaming_callback=streaming_callback)
tornado.simple_httpclient.HTTPTimeoutError: Timeout during request
Cannot send error response after headers written
```

The `HTTPTimeoutError`: I have tried to add `defaults=dict(request_timeout=180)` to `AsyncHTTPClient()` but then I get `Timeout in request queue` besides the `Cannot send error response after headers written`. But I assume something fundamental is wrong with the code for downloading the file.

Using Tornado version 6.3.2, Python 3.9.

```
from tornado.web import RequestHandler, Application
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient
from tornado import version as tornado_version
import asyncio
import os

class MainHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('templates/embed.html')

class DownloadHandler(RequestHandler):
    async def get(self, fname):
        url = 'http://localhost:8888/data/test.csv'
        filename = 'new.csv'
        self.set_header('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream')
        self.set_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=%s' % filename)

        self.flush()

        def streaming_callback(chunk):
            self.write(chunk)
            self.flush()

        client = AsyncHTTPClient()
        response = await client.fetch(url, streaming_callback=streaming_callback)

        self.finish()

def make_app():
    print(tornado_version)
    return Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
        (r'/data/(.*)', DownloadHandler)    
    ])

async def main():
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    shutdown_event = asyncio.Event()
    await shutdown_event.wait()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

embed.html

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <a href="/data/" download="test.csv">DOWNLOAD</a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

test.csv

```
x,y
0,1
3,5
```